# python: easiest way to get a string of spaces of length N

Tags: python, string

What's the easiest way to generate a string of spaces of length N in Python?

(besides something like this, which is multiline and presumably inefficient for large n:

```
def spaces(n):
  s = ''
  for i in range(n):
    s += ' '
  return s
```

)

Comment: I plus'd this back from -1 since I don't think it is an unreasonable question if you didn't know the '*' operator works on strings.

Comment: @DeepYellow: thanks. I figured maybe there wasn't a shortcut or any shortcut would be cryptic/ugly. Now I'm glad I asked!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

try this, simple, only one line:

```
    ' ' * n
```

Comment: cool! where's this documented? I can't seem to find it in the python docs (the canonical can't-use-punctuation-in-google-search problem)

Comment: I'm flagging this question because you clearly padded it to bypass the character limit. I'm joking by the way. Maybe.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods, http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq. Fortunately, most operators, like multiplication, also have a word-y name.

Comment: Did you try googling 'Python string multiplication'?

Answer (score 5):

You could do it as a function:

```
def spaces(n):
    return ' ' * n
```

Or just use the expression:

```
' ' * n
```

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as:

```
s = ' ' * N
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head:

```
spaces = lambda x: ' ' * x
```

Answer (score 1):

All these point mongers are no fun, and their simple answers stink.

The true answer is as follows:

```
def give_me_spaces(n):
    return (lambda : ''.join(' ' for _ in xrange(n)))()
```

Also it's clearly superior because it uses functional programming.

Comment: I think this will also compile as valid Haskell.

Comment: upvote for being funny :)

Answer (score 1):

Had to dig through my python helper functions to find this, but here it is. It's served me well.

```
spaces = (lambda n: 
          (lambda z: z(lambda f: lambda m:'' if m <= 0 else ' ' + f(m - 1))(n))
          (lambda f:(lambda x:f(lambda*a:x(x)(*a)))(lambda x:f(lambda*a:x(x)(*a)))))
```

Comment: upvote for comedic effect :)